# I have to reinstall GRUB to fix grub-rescue but boot partition is ntfs

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, ntfs

My computer has dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu. I updated Windows and this made the computer boot into grub-rescue. It also broke the 'Windows' option on GRUB, which I repaired with [boot repair cd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), so right now my computer boots into grub-recue, from where I can manually access GRUB and from there boot into Windows or Ubuntu.

I want to skip the manual part of grub-rescue, but all I've found on the internet is that I should reinstall GRUB with

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sdaX
```

with sdaX being the boot partition. In my case, I used

```
 sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

to discover that it's sda1. However, /dev/sda1 is formatted as NTFS and grub-install complains about it and won't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Grub is usually installed in /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1 or any of the other partitions. That way it's written into the master boot record at the very start of the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by SpiderPig on his comment to the original post :

> Grub is usually installed in /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1 or any of the other partitions. That way it's written into the master boot record at the very start of the disk.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/691902)

Comment: It's a self-answer to be able to mark the question as solved. If this is the wrong way or unaccepted I'll delete the answer.

Comment: You are welcome to post the *complete* answer, but referencing some other information is a comment, not an answer.